# Start Selenium RC server automatically

Tags: bash, selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc

How can I automatically start and stop the Selenium RC server when I run my phpunit tests?

I thought I could create a little bash script that does something like this (does not work though):

```
java -jar ~/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.0b3.jar &
phpunit --configuration suite.xml &&
killall java
```

Surely there's a way to do that right?  To make the first line run in the background, and the second block execution until completion.

Or is there another good way of doing this?  Does phpunit have a facility for running a process first?

I feel like I need to completely automate this because if I forget to start the server, phpunit doesn't even throw any errors, it just skips the tests!

Comment: Try looking into xinetd. It may solve your problem.

Comment: Return the pid from the java command and only kill that pid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you want to run shell script, java or php code ?

php code : exec("/path to file/script.sh");

java code : Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(/path to file/script.sh);

same for bat file.
and that script contains the command launching of selenium server or directly execute the command for launching server. Please be clear about your question and in which language??????

Comment: php, hence the phpunit.  Didn't think of running the process directly from php -- that'll work.

Comment: Let me clear about your problem, you want to start the selenium server automatically through some code. You can run a process by php-unit as we are doing that thing with java-junit same tool as php-unit used for testing. In Junit we are using the annotations that specifies the which code should be executed by Junit. Similarly you can add annotations in your code for specifying that phpunit will run it.

Answer (score 1):

(Just for fun)

```
TMPFILE=`mktemp` 
SELENIUMJAR=~/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.0b3.jar

bash  -c  "echo $$ &&       java -jar  '${SELENIUMJAR}'" > "$TMPFILE" &
                            sleep 0.1                             
pid=`head -1 <              "$TMPFILE"`
phpunit   --configuration   suite.xml
kill      "$pid"   ;        sleep   2 
kill -9   "$pid"   ;        sleep 0.1 
rm        "$TMPFILE"
```